# How do you call an organisation that helps young adults gain work experience?

Tags: word-request

I am working at an organisation that helps young adults/adolescents who receive income supplement/welfare by providing them with a job at said organisation for a period of 3 or 6 months, after which they can (hopefully) find a regular job or go back to school. If translated literally, it would be learning-working company, but I don't know if it would be called learning company or is there a special word for such an organisation?

Comment: This phrase can also be used in a broader context, but this company could be seen as a *stepping stone* for the young adults towards a better job.

Comment: That sounds good. I asked my friend from London as well and she suggested job rehabilitation scheme for underpriviliged people, but yours is more convenient when used in a conversation haha. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then, so that this question is resolved ;)

Answer (score 1):

When this sort of thing is offered to a job seeker through the job centre, it is called a work placement, but there isn't a word for the company, it's just 'this company is offering work placements'.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the phrase *stepping stone*:

> a circumstance that assists progress towards some goal ([source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stepping+stone))

The company can be seen as *a stepping stone* for young adults towards a better job.

As the definition shows, this phrase can also be used in many other contexts.